# golang ast package, how to get the caller struct from *ast.SelectorExpr

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "context"
        "service"
    )
    
    type LockService struct {}

    func main() {
        s := &LockService{}
        s.LockCouponService(ctx, couponID)
    }
```

how to get LockCouponService called by object(LockService).

and are there any posts giving to me to learn

I try to parse it, but failed.

my code is here

```
var structToMethods = map[string][]string{}
var normalMethods = map[string][]string{}

// https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/writing-multi-package-analysis-tools-for-go/
func main() {

    for _, f := range files {
        pkg := f.Name.Name
        fmt.Println("pkg: ", pkg)
        ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {

            fun, ok := n.(*ast.FuncDecl)
            if !ok {
                return true
            }
            fmt.Println("====================")
            name := "" // 找打方法接受者
            if fun.Recv != nil {
                for _, v := range fun.Recv.List {

                    switch xv := v.Type.(type) {
                    case *ast.StarExpr:
                        if si, ok := xv.X.(*ast.Ident); ok {
                            name = si.Name
                        }
                    case *ast.Ident:
                        name = xv.Name
                        //fmt.Println("xxxxx", xv.Name)

                    }
                    fmt.Println("=====fun.Recv name", name)
                }
            }

            callFuns := []string{}
            for _, l := range fun.Body.List {
                fmt.Printf("l type: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(l))

                e, ok := l.(*ast.ExprStmt)
                if ok {
                    cc, ok := e.X.(*ast.CallExpr)
                    if ok {
                        fmt.Println("cc.Fun type: ", reflect.TypeOf(cc.Fun))
                        se, ok := cc.Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr) // 拿到a.b 的调用关系

                        if ok {

                            callFuns = append(callFuns, se.Sel.String()) // 函数名
                            //函数名
                            fmt.Printf("pkg or more: %s, type: %s, fun_name: %s\n", se.X, reflect.TypeOf(se.X), se.Sel) // 包 或者 变量名，比如 repo 是包，myrepo 是 变量名, 函数名
                            // pkg: &{s repo}, type: *ast.SelectorExpr
                            // pkg: s, type: *ast.Ident, fun_name: LockCouponService
                            _, ok := se.X.(*ast.Ident)
                            if ok {
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            fmt.Printf("fun recv, method, call functions: %v, %v, %v\n", name, fun.Name.String(), callFuns)

        
            return true
        })

    }
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(structToMethods, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println("structToMethods", string(b))
    b, _ = json.MarshalIndent(normalMethods, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println("normalMethods", string(b))
}
```

result is a map. the key is the struct type(like LockService), and value is the method name(like LockCouponService), (LockService may in other packages)

[LockService]=>LockCouponService